# How to send input from one React component to other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a login page. When the user submits the form, the username should be rendered on the dashboard. I am unable to figure that out.

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Back from "./Back";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Back />
      <div>
        <form className="login-form">
          <h1 className="form-heading">Login</h1>
          <input
            className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your Username"
          />
          <input
            className="form-input"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
          />
          <button className="form-button">
            <Link to={"/dashboard"}>Login</Link>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Near the top of your component tree, have a state for the name. Then pass that down to whoever needs it via props or context.

Comment: u can also pass state via location path see the documentation of useLocation it can also helps

Comment: @NicholasTower That would work if i had to return the component. I have linked the dashboard component using <Link> tag(react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share data between two components, the standard react approach is to [lift the state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components) to a parent component, then pass it down (through props or context). For example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login setUser={setUser}/>}
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard user={user}/>}
    </Routes>
  )
}

const Login = ({ setUser }) => {
  return (
    // ...
    <Link to="/dashboard" onClick={() => setUser('bob')}
    // ...
  );
}

const Dashboard = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello {user}!
    </div>
  )
}
```